# Javascript - Create artificial text indent (tab) on keydown inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i need a div instead of a textarea (long story short, so that the box can read html).

However one problem i have come accross is divs don't allow you to just press the Tab key to indent text. So i was wondering if there is a way to essentially simulate the tab press.

I would imagine it is something along the line of:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('keydown keyup',function(e){
      var spaces = e.type=="keydown" ? 
      if(e.which==9){
          insert 4 spaces...  
      }
    });

});
```

This should essentially do what an indent does?

Im still new to Javascript so i apologise if this was something simple.

Comment: What does *"so that the box can read html"* mean? You can display HTML in a `div` if you pass HTML to the `textContent` property of the `div`.

Comment: This is rather an HTML issue. HTML ignores leading white-space characters, you'd need four `&nbsp;`s. And don't forget to prevent the default action of the tab key.

Comment: @Teemu Or, wrap the spaces in a `<pre>` element.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sure, but a div was demanded ...

Comment: @Teemu But, the `pre` can be nested in the `div`

Comment: Can you use CSS like this `div {text-indent: 20px;}` it will indent only first row in a text [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-indent)

Comment: actually, `pre` instead of `div` would be sufficient too, it'll make many things easier, and still renders HTML.

Comment: this fiddle might be able to help https://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/7s40cp1a/1/

Comment: so i've tried interpreting what they have for my work but this isn't working, any idea why? https://jsbin.com/xefimujaja/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qvvkg5j/). It uses `pre` element instead of `div`, but that shouldn't be a problem.